htaccess regex: How to avoid multiple redirects and still satisfy 2x2x2 no-duplicate Google requirements
It's strange but there was no such question yet: Each of the following rewrites is trivial when coded separate; but how to construct regex(es) to have all of them in a single rewrite?

http -> https
www. -> (no www subdomain)
/index.php -> /  (if %{REQUEST_URI} has no GET params or so)
(if url points to a directory without trailing slash) -> (add trailing slash)

Most URLs have 2x2=4 or 2x2x2=8 duplicates which prevent Google-indexing.
For 1+2+3 I've received an elegant single-rewrite solution by @MrWhite:
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect HTTP and/or WWW and remove "index.php" (if any)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*?)\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)(?:(^|/)index\.php)?$ https://%1/$1$2 [R=301,L]

Will there be someone who can solve 1+2+3+4 ?

But if it is on, it will cause a redirect before any of the other stuff above can come into play. So if the goal here is to get "everything" done using just one single redirect, it would have to be turned off, and handled using additional conditions inserted into the above. One check against %{REQUEST_URI} with the -d flag, and a second one to check that it does not end with / - and then you'd have to incorporate it into the above using the right combination of (implicit) AND and OR ...

Why do you want to avoid multiple redirects?  Short redirect chains are perfectly fine.  I'd only worry if you are chaining more than 10 redirects.

Very good point @CBroe. I could not combine AND/OR clauses in the same rule so doing this in 2 rules In the answer below but still doing redirect only once.

@StephenOstermiller I want only one redirect ...just as a challenge! I like to see sophisticated code solutions. :)

This is how you can do all this in a single redirect:
RewriteEngine On

## remove www, trailing slash and turn on https in same external redirect

# turn directory slash off by mod_dir
DirectorySlash off

# for directory URI add a trailing slash and set env variable DSLASH
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,E=DSLASH:1]

# redirect if DSLASH is set or www is present or https is missing
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_DSLASH} =1 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([^:]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?(?:index\.php)?$ https://%1/$1 [R=302,L,NC,NE]

Once you verify it is working fine, replace R=302 to R=301. Avoid using R=301 (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.
PS: Do remember that search engines will take few weeks of time to index your pages again after this change.

It seems working well on the test part of my production site! Finally I'm going to use 307 permanent redirect as I have one case where index.php is followed by GET part to be retained.

That's good to know, suggest you to use 308 instead of 307 (temporary redirect)
